Am I right that most YouTube answers to the question "What is the $\sqrt{i}$" miss an easy method
The question what is the square root of i? appears in many Math-related YouTube posts because, they claim, it has been (or maybe frequently is) posed in university entrance exams or interviews.
What puzzles me is that the algebraic method given by most (all?) of the YouTube posters seems to be more complicated than necessary. An A-Level student refugee from Ukraine showed me this simpler method which she said is taught at high school there.
My question is, does the Ukrainian student's method really work, and if so, why isn't it used by the YouTubers?
YouTubers' method
The YouTubers' method is something like this:
Express the solution as an unknown complex number: $\sqrt{i} = a + bi$
Square both sides: $$i = (a  + bi) ^ 2
                       \implies i = a^2 + (bi)^2 + 2abi
                       \implies i = a^2 - b^2 + 2abi$$
This is equivalent to: $$0 + 1i = (a^2 - b^2) + 2abi$$
So, considering real and imaginary parts separately, we get simultaneous equations
$$(a^2 - b^2) = 0$$
$$        2ab = 1$$
They then go on from there to solve for $a$ and $b$ which takes quite a few steps but is simple enough.
Ukrainian high school method
We know that:
$$(1 + i) ^ 2 = (1 + i)(1 + i) $$
$$ = 1 + 2i - 1 $$
$$                        = 2i$$
Hence: $$\sqrt { (1 + i) ^ 2 } = \sqrt { 2i }$$
$$           \implies ( 1 + i ) = \pm \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{i}$$
Rearranging: $$\sqrt{i} = ( 1 + i ) / \pm \sqrt{2}$$
$$\implies \sqrt{i} = \pm( 1/\sqrt{2} + i/\sqrt{2} )$$
Is this simpler method really as valid as it seems?

Don't see any issue here

Please use MathJax for your mathematics; this is hard to read (see here for help). Also please use quotation blocks (or nothing at all) instead of code blocks.

The only thing I would say is, most newbies to complex numbers do not "know" the fact, "$(1+i)^2 = 2i$"

The point of the first algorithm is that it works for every complex number, and doesn't rely on guessing the correct answer.

You can also use $i^{1/2}=\left(e^{2\pi ik + i\pi/2}\right)^{1/2}=e^{\pi ik + i\pi/4}$ with unique values for $k\in{0,1}$

Thanks for all your comments and thanks to @user1361816 for cleaning up my formulas!

The only issue is that the "Ukrainian method" starts by essentially making a lucky guess.  Sure, once you know $(1+i)^2$ is a real multiple of $i$, the rest is trivial, but how did you know to try $1+i$?  What would the Ukrainians do for $\sqrt{1+2i}$?

Thanks, that makes good sense - YouTubers' method is more general and can be applied for more complex situation, rather than by showing the answer from a previously established fact. It's interesting that this perhaps illustrates the difference in educational approaches - in one case the objective is to teach the quickest/smartest way to do something, almost by rote; the other case is to teach the principles that underlie working with complex numbers. The UKR student also said that a lot of her maths study years ago was learning formulas by heart to be applied to different situations.

I will ask her about $\sqrt{1+2i}$ !

This is a valid method, but it requires some intuition, as not everybody would know that $(i+1)^2$ results in a value that allows for an easier solution. Since all complex numbers must be of the form $a+bi$, it feels more obvious to most viewers to start there, and work your way towards $i$. However, another alternate method that I think is even easier would be to use the form $r $cis$(\theta)$ for complex numbers, as you can directly work backwards from $i$. Specifically, since $i = 1\cdot $cis$(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi)$, we know $\sqrt{i} = \sqrt{1} \cdot $cis$(\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}{2}) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

+1 for the alternate method. But please include $\text{cis}(\pi/2+2n\pi)$ to get the ‘other’ square root, i.e, the negative of the one you’ve already got
